# use html and javascript for file selection dialog in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter

In a jupyter notebook I'd like to use html/javascipt for a file selection dialog instead of tkinter.  After some messing around I was able to get this to work and even make the result available to the python kernel.  BUT, now I think I see why no one else does this... javascript is not aware of the full path to these files.

I was quite proud of this (inside of a jupyter cell):

```html
%%html
<input type="file" accept=".dat" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var output = [];
        IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("lstFiles=[]");
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("lstFiles.append('" + f.name + "')");
            output.push('<li><strong>', f.name, '</strong></li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

then in another cell...

```py
print(lstFiles)
```

This gets me the list of files, but not the path.  Is there any trick to getting the path?  Or even the browser's last used location?

Comment: the path is NOT avaiable in javascript form upload, only the filename. There is NO way the path to file is known

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is what I feared.  I was hoping there was some jupyter magic that could be leveraged.  I was able to get the path by searching for the returned files via `os.walk` (in python) but this is not very clean or efficient.  I guess for now the best option is tkinter.

Comment: This is not allowed by Javascript due to security concerns, see also [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav).